# Prove that a sequence has no limit

Tags: calculus, limits, complex-numbers

Given $Z_n=\arg{\frac{i^n}{n}}$, how do I show that it has no limit?

Comment: Produce subsequences converging to two different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that

- $i^2=-1$
- $i^3=-i$
- $i^4=1$
- $i^5=i$

then we have that

- for $n=4+4k$ even $Z_n=\arg{\frac{i^n}{n}}\to 0$
- for $n=2+4k$ even $Z_n=\arg{\frac{i^n}{n}}\to \pi$

Comment: Okay I understood. But I guess the answer is these 4 values - $-\pi, -{\frac{\pi}{2}}, 0, {\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Comment: @user3132457 To prove that a sequence has not limit we need to exhibit at least two subsequences with different limit, we don't need to show more of that.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Observe that $Z_n$ takes only four values.

Comment: 4 values? I get only one, and it's ${\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Comment: @user3132457 Consider first the first four elements.